# how do you view .go files from imported packages you've installed?

Tags: go, package

Right now, I have imported a package. In my case it is

`import "crypto/ecdsa"`

This package contains a file called `ecdsa.go`. I'd like to view it, however I don't know where to see it. I can't seem to find it in my working directory. Is the file hidden? Or is it installed globally by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package is a part of the Go project. You can find it in your `<go-root-path>/src` directory.

You can find your "go root path" by running `go env GOROOT`.

Probable location of `Go` in linux is `/usr/local/go`

Answer (score 1):

Go standard library packages are located in `GOROOT/src`.

For `GOROOT`, run

```
go env GOROOT
```

For example, for package `import "crypto/ecdsa"` file `ecdsa.go` on Linux,

```
$ go env GOROOT
/home/peter/go
$ ls /home/peter/go/src/crypto/ecdsa/ecdsa.go
/home/peter/go/src/crypto/ecdsa/ecdsa.go
$
```